# django-1.8: "XXXView"object has no attribute 'add_error'

Tags: python, django

I tried to use "add_error" function in django 1.8. Then I got the error "has no attribute of add_error". 
Thanks in advance for your any help.

**views.py**

```
class FinalView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'XXX'
    template_name = 'XXX.html'
    model = Final

    def get_queryset(self):
        form = InputForm(self.request.GET)        
        if form.is_valid():
            department = form.cleaned_data['department']
            person = form.cleaned_data['person']

            if department !="" and person !="":
                if Final.objects.filter(department=department,person=person).exists():
                    queryset=Final.objects.filter(department=department,person=person)
                else:
                    self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists')) ------here reports error----
            return queryset
        return Final.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
```

**traceback**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  159.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\XXX\XXXX\views.py" in get_queryset
  70.                     self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
Exception Type: AttributeError at /final/
Exception Value: 'FinalView' object has no attribute 'add_error'
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the traceback?

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr, added for your reference, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`add_error` needs to be applied to a Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error), not a ListView.

Change this:

```
self.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
```

To this:

```
form.add_error(ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
```

---

As per the comment about the new exception, `add_error` takes two arguments:

> `Form.add_error(field, error)`
>
> This method allows adding errors to specific fields from within the Form.clean() method, or from outside the form altogether; for instance from a view.
>
> The `field` argument is the name of the field to which the errors should be added. If its value is `None` the error will be treated as a non-field error as returned by `Form.non_field_errors()`.

The `error` argument can be a simple string, or preferably an instance of `ValidationError`.

In your case, since this relevant for two fields, you probably want:

```
form.add_error(None,ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))
```

Comment: thanks. After the change, there is error of "Exception Value: add_error() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)" for the same line.

Comment: do you think if I should use "add_error" or not in my case? Because I have more than 1 fields. And this method doesn't allow to put something like "form.add_error("department","person",ValidationError('No corresponding data exists'))"